# Laravel Livewire call livewire component from web route conditionally

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-livewire

I have 2 different dashboard components I want to conditionally route, ideally they'd be using the same route name and then based on the user's role, it would direct them to the appropriate component. I started by trying to use a `CheckRole` middleware with this code:

```
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $roleId = $request->user()->role->id;

        switch ($roleId) {
            case Config::get('roles.internal'):
                if ($request->route()->getName('dashboard')) {
                    break;
                }
                return redirect()->route('dashboard');
            case Config::get('roles.client.client_admin'):
                if ($request->route()->getName() == 'client-admin-dashboard') {
                    break;
                }
                return redirect()->route('/client-dashboard');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

and in my web routes file:

```
    Route::get('/', Dashboard::class)->name('dashboard')->middleware('checkRole');

    Route::get('/', ClientAdminDashboard::class)->name('client-admin-dashboard')->middleware('checkRole');
```

I don't think this is ideal, and while it works in terms of just re-routing things, it causes issues with any links I have to the `dashboard` route for some reason.

```
<a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}" class="nav-link">
```

I get `Route [dashboard] not defined.`

Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like this (this doesn't work, obviously):

```
Route::get('dashboard', function(){
        $roleId = Auth::user()->role->id;

        switch ($roleId) {
            case Config::get('roles.internal'):
                return Route::get(Dashboard::class);
            case Config::get('roles.client.client_admin'):
                return Route::get(ClientAdminDashboard::class);
        }
});
```

I've also tried this:

```
    Route::get('dashboard', function () {
        $roleId = Auth::user()->role->id;

        switch ($roleId) {
            case Config::get('roles.internal'):
                return redirect()->to('/dashboard');
                break;
            case Config::get('roles.client.client_admin'):
                return redirect()->to('/client-admin-dashboard');
                break;
        }
    });
```

Is there a way to accomplish something like the above, and do away with my `CheckRole` middleware?

Comment: Why even use separate routes? Can't you just use one route and just display a different view based on user role?

Comment: @Yinci I could, but the data displayed will be a good bit different and I'd like to avoid a bunch of conditional crap if possible. If there's no way then I can certainly go that route, but I figured I'd try to figure this out first.

Comment: Well you can't have 2 routes with the same URI, no. Because you must understand that Laravel just goes through the list of routes top to bottom trying to see if the current URI matches the signature, and that will always get you the first route. In this case, it's even overwriting the already existing URI with the "new" name. Either you need to build separate URIs, and if you don't want that, you must change the controller (e.g. fetching the data on role basis or using different views)

Comment: ok, I'll just handle it within the controller.